# Does Windows 8 have more restrictive permissions for applications?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, permissions, windows-8, windows-installer

I have an MSI installer for an application I wrote. The installer works fine on Windows 7. I decided to do a smoke test on it on Windows 8 today and it blew up on a WMI query. My knee jerk reaction was that something was wrong with my WMI query, but after several hours of digging (and finding additional errors), I'm starting to think that there's a systemic issue that isn't related to my code.

Specific instances I've found are:

- Failure of a WMI query. I tried to query a particular namespace. I compared the security permissions of the namespace between my Windows 7 and 8 machines and they're they same. I *was* able to get the query to run on the 8 machine if I added "INTERACTIVE" to the WMI namespace ACL (it only had SYSTEM and Administrators originally), which led me to find the next issue...
- Failure to open a registry key in LOCAL_MACHINE. I commented out the block that used the key, which led me to the next issue...
- Failure to open a file in \"Program Files"

What I've done:

- UAC was all the way off at first, but I've turned it on (fully up, notifies me for everything).
- Tinkered with the WMI namespace's ACL
- Tried using impersonation in the WMI query

Am I missing some trick for Windows 8?

(code is C#, .NET 4.0)

Comment: A program requires administrator privliages to write to `Program Files` and `Program Filesx86` are you testing Windows 7 with UAC turned off?  Sounds like Windows 7 was eating the errors, the last two errors, are proper behavior.

Comment: Can you articulate how you wired the C# to the MSI?  EXE, DTF CA?  How is the CA scheduled (context, sequence ) and all those details.  It's not enough to say it worked on Win7. You might have a preexisting condition.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the code is wired to the MSI; I didn't write the installer. I know that my project spits out DLLs that are called by the MSI somehow.

Comment: Those are important details to know to have any hope of troubleshooting this.  The hosting model for your DLL's is critical.

Comment: @Ramhound You were basically right. I've self-answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 differs from Windows 7/Vista in how it handles UAC being turned off. In 7/Vista, programs were given high integrity level, whereas in 8 programs are given medium integrity level.

Source: http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/140/

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't given me much to work with so I'm going to make a lot of assumptions and go out on a limb based on failures from other installers I've seen on Windows 8.

Make sure you have the same versions of .NET on the Windows 8 as you do Windows 7.  Go in and install .NET 3.5 / 4.0 as well as 4.5.

I've seen several installers (TFS Power Tools for one) that have managed code custom actions written using InstallUtil that are bound to one version of the framework and throw errors when you only have .NET 4.5.

The fix to this of course is to use Wix/DTF custom actions instead and use the CustomAction.Config to specify the supported runtimes and allow legacy activation policy.